# TPT Base Class Primary Key Identity convention

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm using code first, and TPT inheritance. An entity's base type table is being generated without an Identity on its primary key. (I can post code if it's helpful) I.E. My person table has a primary key, but not 'Is Identity'.  The sub class tables are generated as expected.

Since it's not generating the primary key for the base type, I tried to add `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` to the Map, which broke the model, and I get an error saying:

> Conflicting configuration settings were specified for property 'Id' on type 'Orion.Data.Entities.Person':  DatabaseGeneratedOption = None conflicts with DatabaseGeneratedOption = Identity.

I've searched for anywhere that may be specifying 'DatabaseGeneratedOption.None' for that property, and it's not in my code. I assume it's a configuration convention in EF6.  I've tried debugging into .net to find where it's breaking, with no sucess.

So the question is, what convention may be causing this that I can disable?  Or is there something else at play here?

EDIT:
Base Mapping:

```
public abstract partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
}

public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(25);

        this.Property(t => t.LastName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(25);

        this.ToTable("People");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        //this.Property(t=>t.Id).HasColumnName("Id").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");

        // Relationship
        this.HasOptional(x => x.User)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Person).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasMany(a => a.Addresses).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

Inherited Class:

```
public partial class ClientRep : Person
{
    public ClientRep()
    {
        this.Jobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>();
    }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsPrimaryContact { get; set; }
    public string JobContactType { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
public class ClientRepMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClientRep>
{
    public ClientRepMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.ToTable("People_ClientRep");
        this.Property(t => t.ClientId).HasColumnName("ClientId");
        this.Property(t => t.IsPrimaryContact).HasColumnName("IsPrimaryContact");
        this.Property(t => t.JobContactType).HasColumnName("JobContactType");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");

        this.HasMany(t => t.Jobs)
            .WithMany(t => t.ClientReps)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("JobClientRep");
                    m.MapLeftKey("ClientRep_Id");
                    m.MapRightKey("Job_Id");
                });

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Client)
            .WithMany(t => t.ClientReps)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClientId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Then in my DbContext:

```
public partial class ProgramDbContext : DbContext, IProgramDbContext
{
    static OrionDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new OrionContextSeedInitializer());
    }
    public OrionDbContext()
        : base("ConnectionString")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    //No DbSet for Person
    public IDbSet<ClientRep> ClientRep { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<ContactPerson> ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<OtherPerson1> OtherPerson1{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Conventions.AddBefore<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>(new InheritanceKeyConvention());
        //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>();

        //abridged
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClientRepMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContactPersonMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OtherPerson1Map());

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        //    .Property(a => a.Id)
        //    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
```

It appears to be related to `StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention` - that appears to assign the Identity to all my other entities, but this one doesn't get it...I assume something to do with it being an abstract class.  I've tried to override that configuration with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
.Property(a => a.Id)
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

but it still conflicts.

Comment: Posted..didn't want to blow everyone up with useless code, but there is an example of an inherited class.  The other 4 are basically the same, just different properties.  I also put my DbContext, or at least some parts of it.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: I also noticed that I have DbSets for my inherited classes, but not the base class.  That doesn't match up with what I'm seeing in some references...Is that incorrect?

Comment: I did remove the DbSets for the inherited classes, and add the base class as I believe that is correct, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that was 8 hours of ridiculous adventure!

Backstory: I imported the code first by doing a reverse engineer existing database.

That generated my inherited entities to have a primary key, but not Identity on them.  I removed all the mappings to the Id property, because that does not exist on the inherited entity, only the base.  (This all makes so much more sense now...sheesh, what a waste of a day!)

My inherited class &  mapping now looks like this:

```
public partial class ClientRep : Person
{
    public ClientRep()
    {
        this.Jobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>();
    }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsPrimaryContact { get; set; }
    public string JobContactType { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
public class ClientRepMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClientRep>
{
    public ClientRepMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("People_ClientRep");
        this.Property(t => t.ClientId).HasColumnName("ClientId");
        this.Property(t => t.IsPrimaryContact).HasColumnName("IsPrimaryContact");
        this.Property(t => t.JobContactType).HasColumnName("JobContactType");
        this.HasMany(t => t.Jobs)
            .WithMany(t => t.ClientReps)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("JobClientRep");
                    m.MapLeftKey("ClientRep_Id");
                    m.MapRightKey("Job_Id");
                });
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Client)
            .WithMany(t => t.ClientReps)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClientId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

And once I removed those remnants from the reverse engineer, everything generated as desired.